# Plugin Services not include when instance of Service declared

Tags: grails

I am trying to refactor a service that depends on a plugin's service.

The original service works fine but when I moved out portions of the service and placed them into another class to be called for some reason the plugin service instance does not get set

Original Service

```
package myPackage

class MyService {
  def pluginService

  def myMethod(args){
    def methodVar = pluginService.pluginMethod()
    // Do stuff with methodVar

    return methodVar
  }

  ...

  def myVar = myMethod(args)
  ...
}
```

I moved the methods to my Groovy class so I can just reference it in the service and break up the monolithic file that I have

new class file

```
package myPackage

    class MyClass {
      def pluginService

      def myMethod(args){
        def methodVar = pluginService.pluginMethod()
        // Do stuff with methodVar

        return methodVar
      }  
    }
```

Modified Service

```
package myPackage

class MyService {
      def myClass
     ...
     def myVar = myClass.myMethod(args)
     ...
}
```

By doing this at runtime I get "cannot invoke pluginMethod on null" on the `def methodVar = pluginService.pluginMethod()` line in MyClass file. I added `import PluginPackage.PluginService` to the class file which removed the null error but now it's giving me "cannot invoke pluginMethodFromOtherPluginSerivceFromSamePlugin on null" error.

Did I forget to declare something when I moved the code out of the service and placed it into the class file?

I've been searching the web and can't seem to find any solution to this problem.

Any help will would be appreciated.

Comment: Where in the project's folder hierarchy is the new class stored?

Comment: I stored the class file in src/groovy/myPackage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class resides in src/groovy then your service will not be automatically injected into your class. I am familiar with a couple of ways you can fix this:

1. Create a UtilityService instead, which resides with other services.
2. Manually inject the service into your src/groovy classes using the application context. Here's a [helpful link](http://www.qlambda.com/2013/02/inject-service-class-into-srcgroovy.html)

Comment: Thanks, I was banging my head over this issue for a while. I used Option 2 and it worked perfectly. Once again thanks for your help.